# Partitioned matrices in R

Tags: r

I’m looking for a code to create matrix B from matrix A, this is a very simple example my real matrix A is (500 x500) and B11(50x50)

```
1 2 = A        
   3 4

1 1 | 2 2        
1 1 | 2 2        
.----------= B        
3 3 | 4 4        
3 3 | 4 4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a Kronecker product, which is `%x%`:

```
R>A <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
R>A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
R>X <- matrix(1,2,2)
R>X
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
R>A %x% X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    3    3
[2,]    1    1    3    3
[3,]    2    2    4    4
[4,]    2    2    4    4
R>t(A) %x% X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    2
[2,]    1    1    2    2
[3,]    3    3    4    4
[4,]    3    3    4    4
```